# Do Until loop by Restricting user input to email address or domain\ID in PowerShell using Read-Host

Tags: powershell, read-host

Im doing a Do Until loop by Restricting user input to email address or domain\ID in PowerShell using Read-Host. The condition is not working.

Original syntax:

```
do { $answer = Read-Host "yes or no" } until ("yes","no" -contains $answer)
```

Input:

```
$DL1 = "HH@domain.com"
$DL2 = "domain\HH"
$Restriction1 = $DL1.EndsWith('@domain.com')
$Restriction2 = $DL2.StartsWith('domain\')
Output:
True
```

Actual command:

```
Do {$DLO= Read-Host "Enter ID (Email Address or Domain\ID)"}
until ($DLO.EndsWith('@domain.com'),$DLO.StartsWith('Domain\') -match 'true' )
```

Why the condition is not working?

Comment: why do you expect the result to be the STRING `true`? also, what do you get with two booleans connected with a comma?

Comment: also also, the `.StartsWith()` method is _case sensitive_ ... and your `$Restriction2` test will be false since `domain` does not match `Domain`.

Comment: Expectation is to accept only email address (eg.arun@gmail.com)  or ID (eg. gmail/123456) where gmail.com is the domain. If it is a different domain - would prefer to have do loop continued until user provide correct values

Comment: Im not sure what condition to be used. Ask would be to accept the value if either $Restriction1 or $Restriction2 is true inorder to process the input to next section

Comment: yes, but your code is _deeply odd_. [*grin*] [1] the test has two booleans connected by a command and then tests them with `-match "true"`. testing for the STRING `true` instead of the boolean `$True` is quite odd. [2] two booleans connected by a comma is VERY ODD. you would normally test with either an `-and` or with an `-or` depending on if you want both or only one to be true. [3] the items you are testing are _case sensitive_ and your earlier test mixes `domain` and `Domain` ... those cannot match in a case sensitive test.

Comment: The loop is not working if I use -or while it should loop back until I either provide input as xyz@domain.com or domain\xyz 

Can you advise what I am missing

Comment: Template: that I am referring and changing is 
do { $answer = Read-Host "yes or no" } 
until ("yes","no" -ccontains $answer)

Comment: please take a look at my Answer. i think it covers what you need. it is longer, but it seems more obvious to me.

Comment: Thank you so much :-) eeeeeeee. I will test it today and confirm back

Comment: Hi Lee Dailey, Can I have this in Do Until format?

Comment: is there a problem with the `while` version? does it not work? ///// the only difference between `do/until` and `while` is that the test is done _first_ with the `while` and _after_ the loop with the `do/until`. so ... yes, it can be rewritten as such. however, i severely dislike the `do/until` structure, so i will leave rewriting it to you. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

the reason your version fails is that you changed the basic structure of the `while` test from your source. plus, you ignored the fact that `.StartsWith()` and `.EndsWith()` are both *case sensitive*. that last means that `domain` and `Domain` are NOT the same thing. [*grin*]

instead of untangling that, i rewrote the idea in a way that seems more obvious to me.

what it does ...

- creates the constants
- creates regex-escaped versions of the test strings
  the one that ends with a slash won't work without escaping since that is a reserved character. the one that ends with `.com` won't always work without escaping since the dot is "any character" in the regex pattern language.
- sets the input variable to a blank string
- starts a `while` loop
- test for a `null or empty` string
- gets the user input
- `if` tests for a domain id
- `elseif` tests for an email address
- `else` writes a warning & sets the input $Var to a blank string
- after the while loop exits, shows the content of the `$RHInput` variable

the code ...

```
$DomainName = 'Ziggity'
$EmailSuffix = '@{0}.com' -f $DomainName
$ES_Regex = [regex]::Escape($EmailSuffix)
$UserNamePrefix = '{0}\' -f $DomainName
$UNP_Regex = [regex]::Escape($UserNamePrefix)

$RHInput = ''
while ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($RHInput))
    {
    $RHInput = Read-Host ('Enter an ID [ UserName@{0} or {1}UserName ] ' -f $EmailSuffix, $UserNamePrefix)
    if ($RHInput -match "^$UNP_Regex")
        {
        'You entered a domain ID [ {0} ]' -f $RHInput
        }
        elseif ($RHInput -match "$ES_Regex$")
        {
        'You entered an email address [ {0} ]' -f $RHInput
        }
        else
        {
        Write-Warning (    '[ {0} ] is not a valid email address OR a valid domain ID.' -f $RHInput)

        $RHInput = ''
        }
    }

''
$RHInput
```

output while in the `while` ...

```
# 1st run thru
Enter an ID [ UserName@@Ziggity.com or Ziggity\UserName ] : testing@ziggity.com
You entered an email address [ testing@ziggity.com ]

# 2nd run thru
Enter an ID [ UserName@@Ziggity.com or Ziggity\UserName ] : testing\tutu
WARNING: [ testing\tutu ] is not a valid email address OR a valid domain ID.
Enter an ID [ UserName@@Ziggity.com or Ziggity\UserName ] : ziggity\testing
You entered a domain ID [ ziggity\testing ]
```

output after the `while` loop ...

```
# 1st run thru
testing@ziggity.com

# 2nd run thru
ziggity\testing
```